# Cannot Login To Default SQL Server Instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008

I brought my laptop home from work hoping I could get some tasks done over the weekend. Unfortunately, I couldn't login to SQL Server using `Windows Authentication`. I've checked the **SQL Server Configuration Manager** and the instance (`MSSQLSERVER`) is set to **Log On As** `Local System`, which supposedly means that I should be able to login fine using Windows Authentication... or am I missing something here? Note that in the login window, I tried a lot of different combinations and it always keeps telling me that connection failed because the server is not accessible or I'm not authorized to access it.

A little background about how the instance was installed: I installed and configured it myself. I chose the `Mixed Authentication` mode and gave a password to the default `sa` user (which isn't working either by the way). The thing I suspect could be the problem is the fact that I installed the SQL SERVER instance when I was logged in as my `Domain User` at work (`DOMAIN\UserName`). Now I'm at home and I do not have access to the LAN at the office, so I'm logged in as the `{COMPUTERNAME}\Kassem` user.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A windows account has to be added to SQL Server to have any rights.  If you didn't add `{COMPUTERNAME}\Kassem`, you can't login to SQL Server.

The recovery option here is the SA password, which should always work.

To connect to the default instance, connect to `localhost` or `.`.  Connecting to `.\MSSQLSERVER` won't work, even though `MSSQLSERVER` is the default instance name.

Comment: The weird thing is that SA cannot login either! I've entered the Server name as `.\MSSQLSERVER`, `{DOMAIN}\MSSQLSERVER` and both did not work...

Comment: During installation, did you use the default instance or specify an instance name?

Comment: The default instance. And I can see it is called `MSSQLSERVER` in the SQL Server Configuration Manager

Comment: Then you should be able to connect to `localhost`, without specifying an instance

Comment: That did it! Please edit your answer and include the `localhost` trick so I could accept it. Thanks for the help :)